# Create save filenames from userinput in Python

Tags: python, xmpp, user-input, filenames, irc

I'm programming an [IRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) and [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) bot that needs to convert user provided input to a filename. I have already written a function to do this. Is it sane enough?

Here is the code:

```
allowednamechars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_+/$.-'

def stripname(name, allowed=""):
    """ strip all not allowed chars from name. """
    n = name.replace(os.sep, '+')
    n = n.replace("@", '+')
    n = n.replace("#", '-')
    n = n.replace("!", '.')
    res = u""
    for c in n:
        if ord(c) < 31: continue
        elif c in allowednamechars + allowed: res += c
        else: res += "-" + str(ord(c))
    return res
```

It's a whitelist with extra code to remove control characters and replace os.sep, as well as some repaces to make the filename [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) compatible.

The bot in question is at http://jsonbot.googlecode.com.

So what do you think of it?

Comment: What happens if a user gives `../../../../fubar` as a filename? Make sure you always save to the right directory. Also, what happens if the file already exists?

Comment: In particular, on Windows `os.sep` is \, but / also a works as separator.

Comment: Can you explain what is the point of the conversion? Do you need uniqueness? Retrievability? In your code there can be collisions, and it is not clear whether you want to avoid them or not.

Comment: i know this comparison of strings concat, i will use it to make the bot use less memory as it uses a LOT of strings ;] Right now im focusing on making it save ..

Comment: I didn't know / also worked as a seperator on windows, i will take that into account ;]

Comment: The collision thing is something i did want to avoid but somehow that creeped in.

Comment: Consider using a join (res = []; ''.join(res)) to create your string instead of the + concatenations. join is **way** more efficient.
http://skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urllib.quote(name.encode("utf8"))` will produce something human-readable, which should also be safe.  Example:

```
In [1]: urllib.quote(u"foo bar$=+:;../..(boo)\u00c5".encode('utf8'))
Out[1]: 'foo%20bar%24%3D%2B%3A%3B../..%28boo%29%C3%85'
```

Comment: google requirements on file names:
  - It must contain only letters, numbers, _, +, /, $, ., and -.

Comment: i like this solution though ... if i didnt have to deal with App Engine then i would have used it. But if i ever need to upload my shell bot files to the App Engine i want to have the filenames ok.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider just doing `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(name)`, which will always produce a safe name, unless you really want a human-readable file name.  Otherwise, the number of edge cases is pretty long, and if you forget one of them, you've got a security problem.

Comment: I do need the filename to be human readable .. the files are jsonstrings that are generated by the bot but must be human editable if needed. think of configuration files of a bot in where the bot name is important because the user must be able to edit the right configuration file.